# m cup, pour water, graph algorithm, n=(a1+1)(a2+1)...(am+1)

Tags: algorithm

The problem disturbed me for long time. I think the solution shoulde be graph algorithm. Thank a lot

Given m cups c1; c2; ;cm with integer capacity a1; a2; : : : ; am mls respectively. You are only allowed
to perform the following three types of operations:

1. Completely fill one cup.
2. Empty one cup.
3. Pour water from cup ci to cup cj until either ci is empty or cj is full.

Starting from the state in which all cups are empty, you would like to reach the final state in which
cup c1 has x mls of water and all other cups are empty (for some given x). Design an algorithm to findthe minimum number of operations required or report that the desired final state is not reachable. 
Your algorithm must run in time polynomial in n = (a1 + 1)(a2 + 1) : : : (am + 1).

Answer (score 0):

let's say c1 has capacity 5 litres and c2 have that of 3 litres. Their difference is 2 litres. 
So 2 litres of water can be taken in any cup c1 or c2 by following steps- 
1) fill c1 i.e. 5 litres.
2) pour it in c2 until it gets full.
3) empty c2.
4) you have 3 2 liters in c1.

For these m cups, you have m Choose 2 = m!/(m-2)!2! = m*m-1/2 combinations. 
Calculate all those and fill them in hash table with operation also. 
Because 2 litres can be capacity of a cup also difference of 2 cups capacity. We store operation = 1 instead of 3.

Now we have hash set of all possible litres of water we can hold with no of operations. 
All you need to find the minimum length subsequence from that collection of minimum no of operations.